# Create an accordion using tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to create an accordion type of responsive table. I have used the jquery.mobile.js to achieve the responsive layout when the screen size drops below 767px width. So my table turns into Rows where the `THead` has been repeated on each row. What I would like to do is make it so that all rows are collapsed accept the first row. I have this working but when you open the first instance all the rows open. I only want the one you have clicked on to open.

Here is the Jquery:

```
jQuery(function($){
    responsiveTables();
    /*===================
      SB: RESPONSIVE TABLES
    =====================*/
    function responsiveTables() {
        if ($(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.first').append('<button name="button" class="responsiveTableTdLink glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></button>');
            $('.tdCollapse').hide();
            $('button.responsiveTableTdLink').click(function(){
                $('.tdCollapse').slideToggle(100);
                $("table button").toggleClass(function() {
                    if ($(this).parent().is(".glyphicon-chevron-down")) {
                        $("table button").addClass("responsiveTableTdLink glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
                    } else {
                        $("table button").addClass("responsiveTableTdLink glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that what you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/ElmahdiMahmoud/3jBv2/ ?

Comment: we need to see your HTML markup for the table. Where are the classes .first, .tdCollapse, etc. applied?